# Is it possible to log the IP address for SNI in apache logs on errors?

Tags: apache-2.2, sni

Is it possible to log the IP address associated with SNI in the apache logs?
I realize that this is SSL when it connects, so if its not now, Im wondering if
apache would add it so at least we could get the IP address when I see the following
in my logs:

[Wed May 15 04:12:58 2013] [error] No hostname was provided via SNI for a name based virtual host

I ask because I see many hacking/probing attempts and want to use fail2ban to
ban them.

Thanks

Comment: You want to log the IP address of the server? That doesn't seem very useful, and it would certainly be useless for banning.

Answer (score 2):

Have you reviewed the Apache documentation, specifically [the section on custom log formats](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html)?
The answer you seek is almost certainly in the manual - you can log nearly anything you can think of.

In this particular case you want to add the remote IP address (`%a`), and possibly the local IP address (`%A` - though [like Michael pointed out that's probably not very useful if your goal is to ban offenders](https://serverfault.com/questions/508039/is-it-possible-to-log-the-ip-address-for-sni-in-apache-logs-on-errors#comment571917_508039)) to your Error log format.